# CreateMany inside a Create statement in Prisma

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

Hello I'm trying to implement a create statement that takes in an array of another model.
Here are my schemas

```
model House {
  id        String   @id
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  property_name String     @db.VarChar(30)
  house_type    String     @db.VarChar(10)
  beds          Int
  baths         Int
  workspace     Int
  occupied      Boolean    @default(false)
  stay          DateTime[]

  amenities Amenity[]
  room      Room[]

  zipcode    String  @db.VarChar(5)
  address    Address @relation(fields: [address_id], references: [id])
  address_id Int
}

model Address {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

  city       String
  state_code String  @db.VarChar(2)
  house      House[]
}

model Amenity {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

  amenity_name String
  house        House  @relation(fields: [house_id], references: [id])
  house_id     String
}

model Room {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())

  room_number String
  occupied    Boolean @default(false)
  house       House   @relation(fields: [house_id], references: [id])
  house_id    String
}
```

I've tried to add houses with their respective relationships, but this is the only way I've found to do it.

```
createHomeDto.id = uuid();
    const {
      amenities,
      room,
      ...home
    } = createHomeDto;

    await this.prisma.house.create({
      data: home
    });

    Object.entries(amenities).map(async ([key, value]) => {
      await this.prisma.amenity.create({
        data: {
          amenity_name: value.amenity_name,
          house: {
            connect: {
              id: home.id
            }
          }
        }
      })
    });

    Object.entries(room).map(async ([key, value]) => {
      await this.prisma.room.create({
        data: {
          room_number: value.room_number,
          house: {
            connect: {
              id: home.id
            }
          }
        }
      })
    })
```

Is there a more optimal solution to this or a I stuck creating my relationships like so?

Answer (score 2):

Does it answer to your question ?

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries#nested-writes

Edit : if you scroll down this page you will see how to createMany inside the create statement. Look at the given example :

```
const user = await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    email: 'saanvi@prisma.io',
    posts: {
      createMany: {
        data: [{ title: 'My first post' }, { title: 'My second post' }],
      },
    },
  },
  include: {
    posts: true,
  },
})
```